# run opencv routines on CPU and GPU using Opencl

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, opencv, opencl

I want to run opencv routines on CPU and GPU using Opencl to compare the performance. How can I run opencv routines in opencl?? I enable the ocl module in opencv using CMake but how can i call opencv routines ?? I used ocl namespace ( ocl:: ) but they didn't give me the opencv routines!!

I will be grateful if any one can help me.

Note: I am using VS 2008.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can read [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ocl/doc/ocl.html) of ocl module in OpenCV. By the way, are you sure you need specifically OpenCL? Maybe you can use [GPU module](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/gpu.html) of OpenCV (which is based on CUDA as far as I know).

Comment: I read the documentation but it didn't help me.Yes, i need to use the opencl because my project based on opencl. thanks for your help.

Comment: Just to be sure I am getting the problem correctly: when you said that it is not giving you opencv routines do you mean that you get compilation error when using ocl functions or there was a crash in a run-time?

Comment: No, I mean when I write (ocl::) the list of functions appear didn't contain opencv routines.